# Can't see tables in pgAdmin4 that were created through dockerized PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm running PostgreSQL through a Docker container. I entered the container and used `psql` to connect to postgres. I created two databases then created a table in `test_db`. I checked pgAdmin4 and the databases were there but the `students` table is not showing up in the UI. Not sure why if the databases are showing up?

[image: pgAdmin4 alongside sql postgres connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you connected to 'test_db' database in pgadmin, but to 'postgres' database in psql. If you want to see 'students' table from 'test_db' database in psql, you need connect to 'test_db' database firstly instead of 'postgres' database. You can use '\c test_db' command for that in psql, or '-d test_db' command-line parameter when launching psql from command line.